# Drawing border only if parent element doesn't have specific class in Sass

Tags: html, css, sass

I would like to change the behavior of my SASS code. Current SASS code always draws the `border` on `focus` event. It should only draw the `border` when its parent element `select2-container` doesn't have the `select2-container--disabled` class. How can I do this?

**HTML**

```
<select name="product" id="nbp__name-dropdown" class="form-control select2-hidden-accessible" disabled="" data-select2-id="nbp__name-dropdown" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"></select>
<span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--disabled select2-container--focus" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="2" style="width: 377.5px;">
    <span class="selection">
        <span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="select2-nbp__name-dropdown-container">
            <span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-nbp__name-dropdown-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true">
                <span class="select2-selection__placeholder">Select a product...</span>
            </span>
            <span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</span>
```

**SASS**

```
.select2-selection--single {
  &:focus {
    border: 1px solid $focus-border-color;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using `select2-container--disabled` only as an *additional* class, here you go:

```
.select2-container {
  &:not(.select2-container--disabled) {
    .select2-selection--single {
      &:focus {
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> https://gist.github.com/franktopel/1779117580ea0bf5be02aee0e7e27258

```css
.select2-container:not(.select2-container--disabled) .select2-selection--single:focus {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<select name="product" id="nbp__name-dropdown" class="form-control select2-hidden-accessible" disabled="" data-select2-id="nbp__name-dropdown" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"></select>
<span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--disabled select2-container--focus" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="2" style="width: 377.5px;" if="foo">
    <span class="selection">
        <span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-nbp__name-dropdown-container">
            <span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-nbp__name-dropdown-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true">
                <span class="select2-selection__placeholder">Select a product...</span>
            </span>
            <span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</span>
<!-- not disabled -->
<select name="product" id="nbp__name-dropdown" class="form-control select2-hidden-accessible" disabled="" data-select2-id="nbp__name-dropdown" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"></select>
<span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--focus" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="2" style="width: 377.5px;" id="bar">
    <span class="selection">
        <span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-nbp__name-dropdown-container">
            <span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-nbp__name-dropdown-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true">
                <span class="select2-selection__placeholder">Select a product...</span>
            </span>
            <span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</span>
```

Comment: If you check the snippet you see it works. Click on "Select product" to test.

Comment: Of course you need to replace your existing approach with my code.

Answer (score 1):

> It should only draw the border when its parent element
>   select2-container doesn't have the select2-container--disabled class.
>   How can I do this?

I couldn't get your code to work in CodePen, so I made up an example, because I was also curious if you could use :not with a parent.  If I understand you well, you do not want to draw a border if the parent of the element to be bordered does not have the disabled class. Did it in straight CSS, SASS is not involved :)

So this example works - the middle paragraph will not be bordered:

### HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="chalk">
      <p class="one">This one should be bordered</p>
    </div>
    <div class="chalk disabled">
      <p class="one">This one should not be bordered</p>
    </div>
    <div class="chalk">
      <p class="one">This one should be bordered</p>
    </div>
  </body>
```

### CSS

```
div:not(.disabled) .one  {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Why not make your code a runnable snippet? Also probabyl the text of your second `p.one` should involve *not*.